# Arrange images to fit within a container

Tags: jquery, html

I need to arrange my images to fit exactly within a dIV container.
I've found this plugin: http://collageplus.edlea.com/example.html.
It works fine except one important for me issue: I cannot set the number of rows for the images.
For example I have 10 images and want to display them in 3 rows so they fit in the container.
Looking all day for some other plugins but cannot find anything.

Can someone help me?

thank for help in advance!

Comment: You might want to post a question to the community for that plugin which appears to be here:

https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/issues

Comment: the images fit into the container that is specified for the width. So if you want to fit the images 3 at a time they should be all sized the exact same width prior to placing into this plugin. Then after that place them in a 3x+20px (for safety) container and they will be 3 rows.